# How to install libjpeg on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

libjpeg or libjpeg-turbo are requirements for installing [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow), which is [a new requirement for storing images on django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/core/files/images/).  So I need to install Pillow but that won't work until I get `jpeg` support which comes by way of packages called libjpeg or libjpeg-turbo.  I hope that is the case, at least.

This dependency is not an issue on the dev server, but I need to do some work locally, (Macbook Pro OSX 10.11.5).  Haven't been able to do it yet or find a solution to install yet for OSX.  I was hoping I would find something in `pip` or `conda` but there is nothing for OSX.  I have seen there are various normal ways to install on Linux.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install jpeg
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of homebrew, which I also have already.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: This does not work anymore, the library can not be found.

Comment: If I run `brew install libjpeg` I get the same result as with `brew install jpeg` so maybe they renamed it, but it still works for me.

Answer (score 4):

For libjpeg-turbo

```
 brew install jpeg-turbo
```

Then it'll give you instructions on how to add it to your library load path (so that it doesn't conflict with libjpeg, it isn't in the standard paths).

Answer (score 3):

Fresh install of Big Sur (macOS 11.0.1) and Homebrew, then :

```
brew install jpeg
```

Then installed XCode command line tools (required because of zlib) via

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then in zsh for tools to find headers :

```
export CPATH=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include
export LDFLAGS="-L//Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
export CPPFLAGS="-I//Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
```

Lastly in a virtual environment (Python 3.8) :

```
pip install setuptools, wheel, Pillow
```